# How do I check if an input is in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to be able to enter a value and check if it is in a list and if it is then in the list run a the rest of the program wanted.

```
a=input('enter value')
b=(1,2,3,4)
c=(5,6,7,8,9)
if a is in b:
   print 'enter in code thats wanted'
```

Comment: Please read [pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on how to format your python code properly.

Comment: thanks I have gone through a load of python tutorials and regular look up it on the documentation python

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've written it yourself almost correctly, just instead of -

```
if a is in b:
```

it should be -

```
if a in b:
```

Answer (score 6):

condition should be

```
if a in b:
    print 'enter in code thats wanted'
```

Answer (score 1):

- in operator: The ‘in’ operator is used to check if a value exists in a sequence or not. Evaluates to true if it finds a variable in the specified sequence and false otherwise.
- ‘is’ operator: Evaluates to true if the variables on either side of the operator point to the same object and false otherwise.

hence:

```py
if a in b:
    print 'enter in the code that\'s wanted'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this ↓

```
a=input('enter value')
b=(1,2,3,4)
c=(5,6,7,8,9)
if a in b:
print ('enter in code thats wanted')
```